# How to setup dns for multiple subdomains

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, internal-server-error, qtranslate-x

Hello I am trying to create a website in multiple languages. Every language has it own virtual subdomain. So for example here are some urls:
nl.foo.eu, fr.foo.eu, de.foo.eu

My domain that generates all the content is foo.eu, it generates the content and translates it to the right language.

This is done with wordpress and the plugin qTranslate-X.

But everytime when I go to an url like nl.foo.eu the page returns an internal server error 500.

So my question is: Do i need to configure something in my DNS to make this possible?

And could I be doing something else wrong?

I went trough the error log of the server and this is the error i am retrieving:

```
[Fri Apr 17 09:53:21.028095 2015] [core:error] [pid 731951] [client        12.34.56.78:50514] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects   due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase   the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Answer (score 1):

I configured my environment this way:

1. select "Use Pre-Domain Mode (uses http://en.yoursite.com)" in the advanced settings of domain
2. add DNS records; in my hosts file, I added this:
   127.0.0.1   www.example.com
   127.0.0.1   en.example.com
   127.0.0.1   example.com
3. check that your web server is properly configured. I'm using Apache and I have this configuration with wildcard in ServerAlias:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>  
   DocumentRoot /wamp/www/example  
   ServerName www.example.com  
   ServerAlias example.com *.example.com  
   AcceptPathInfo On  
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Sorry for my late reaction, but your hosts file is the same as my directadmin dns management i guess? And how can I check if my webserver is properly configured using directadmin ? I just made a wildcard by setting the following dns record: *.foo.com A 12.34.56.78